# Streaming audio from Win7 PC to Logitech Revue: Added music but can't find it on Revue

Tags: google-tv, audio-streaming

I recently added a Logitech Revue to my Home Theater setup, and so far it has done an excellent job streaming audio and video from my computer... Until I tried to add more media to the computer.

In this case I added some MP3s to my existing library (shared folders); but I can't seem to get it to be found by the Revue.

I tried:

- Choosing "refresh" from the context menu on the Revue while browsing music
- Re-scanning network sources from the root browse dialog in the Logitech Media Player
- Restarting my Revue
- Restarting my PC
- Restarting my Revue (again)
- Re-scanning network sources from the root browse dialog in the Logitech Media Player (again)
- Choosing "refresh" from the context menu on the Revue while browsing music (again)

And after each step, checking to see if the new music was available for streaming to the Revue: it was not.

The music is DRM free, which is the only criteria that is [listed on the Logitech website](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19846/~/playing-music-on-logitech-media-player) for what will or will not be found.

Any other ideas for what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer I was looking for, but so far it has been an all-around better experience to use a different DLNA streaming server. I was using Windows 7 shared folders previously, and after having switched to [TVersity](http://tversity.com), my problems went away. As an added bonus, the media browsing structure is less cluttered and more intuitive. Double win.